# Composition of linear maps (onto map to one-to-one map composition)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, $g:V\rightarrow W$ a linear map. Show that g is surjective $\iff$ For any vector space $U$ the map $g^{\ast}:Hom(W,U) \rightarrow Hom(V,U)$ defined by $g^{\ast}(f) = f\circ g$ is injective.

I've failed too much trying to solve this problem. Any hint could be useful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinkg the notation can become quite heavy at some point, so let's try to make thinkgs easy. You can show that the map $g^*$ is always linear.

Suppose $g$ is surjective. Let $U$ be any vector space. Let's show that the map $g^*$ described above is injective. Suppose $f:W\to U$ satisfies $g^*(f)=0$, that is, $fg=0$. We need to show that $f=0$. Let any $w\in W$. Since $g$ is surjective, $w=g(x)$ for some $x\in V$, so $f(w)=f(g(x))=0$. This proves that $f=0$, and therefore $\ker g^*=0$, which means that $g^*$ is injective.

For the other direction we use the contrapositive: Suppose $g$ is not surjective, and let $v\in W\setminus g(V)$. Let $U=W$. Let's show that $g^*$ is not injective.

We can construct a linear map $f:W\to W$ satisfying $f(v)=v$ and $f(g(V))=0$. For this, take a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $g(V)$, so $\mathcal{B}\cup\left\{v\right\}$ is LI in $W$, and can be extended to a basis $\mathcal{C}$ of $W$. We define $f$ on $W$ by setting $f(v)=v$ and $f(x)=x$ for all other elements $x$ of the basis $\mathcal{C}$. Since $v\neq 0$, this yields $f\neq 0$.

But by definition, we have $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{B}$, so $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in g(V)$, which means that $f(g(v))=0$ for all $v\in V$, so $g^*f=f(g)=0$.

Therefore, $f$ is a nonzero function in $\operatorname{ker} g^*$, so $g^*$ is non-injective.

Comment: This was really helpful because I was thinking on $f \circ g$ being injective, not $g^*$

Comment: I have a question, how can you suppose $U = V$ without the loss of generality?

Comment: @Luke I am not assuming this without loss of generality. We are proving that "If for all $U$, the $g^*$ is injective, then $g$ is surjective". So assume that for all $U$, $g^*$ is injective. **In particular**, if $U=W$, $g^*$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\;g\;$ is surjective and assume $\;f\in\ker g^*\;,\;\;g^*:\text{Hom},(W,U)\to\text{Hom}\,(V,U)\;\implies$

$$g^*(f)=0\implies\color{red}{\forall v\in V}\;,\;\;f\circ g(v)=f(gv)=0\implies g(v)\in \ker f$$

But since $\;g\;$ is surjective, any $\;w\in W\;$ is $\;f(v_w)\;$ , for some $\;v_w\in V\;$, so for any $\;w\in W\;$ we get

$$fw=f(gv_w)=0\implies f=0\implies \ker g^*=0\implies g^*\;\;\text{injective}$$

Perhaps you can do now the other direction by yourself. If you've any problem I shall be back later to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is easy: if $g$ is surjective, $g*$ is injective – in other words, for any $v\colon W\to U$ , if $v\circ g=0$, then $v=0$.

Conversly, suppose $g*$ is injective, and consider the linear map $p\colon W \longrightarrow \operatorname{coker} g=W/g(V)g$.

By definition, $g*(p)=p\circ g=0$, hence$p=0$, which means $W=g(V)$, i.e.  $g$ is surjective.